# Best way to get rid of www. and 

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I want all traffic to go to:

http://www.domain.com

http://domain.com

|

V

http://main.domain.com

I can use .htaccess or maybe something in PHP, I'm using zend framework.  Please note I also have:

http://sub1.domain.com

http://sub2.domain.com

thx

Comment: is it question how to get rid of www or how to redirect requests? Can you be more consisnent in your questions please?

Comment: I need to redirect www. and . requests appropriately to .main., keeping /any/path/info/.  It is for the structure of my Zend Framework setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This rules will preserve the complete uri

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://main.%1/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

PS: I cannot think up how to make second line more portable without explicit domain specification. I will appreciate someone who can correct me.

Comment: Needs mod_rewrite to work, but that's often enabled. These rules go into the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Thorarin: he definitely has it enabled, because of this quote: "requests appropriately to .main., keeping /any/path/info/". But yes, for anyone who will read it later - it is good clarification.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]                                                               RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the ServerName directive ?

Answer (score 1):

The server-side solutions seem a little unnecessary when the Domain Name Server protocol is designed to handle redirects exactly like these. Path info and POST variables are preserved transparently.

If you have access to the DNS records for your website, it is best to use a [CNAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) to redirect users to the proper domain name.

The CNAME points people looking for one domain (e.g. site.com) to another (e.g. main.site.com). This is all done without any work on your server.

Simply add two records to your CNAME records pointing:

```
domain.com => main.domain.com
www.domain.com => main.domain.com
```

If your current DNS provider does not provide this, try using [ZoneEdit](http://www.zoneedit.com/), who have worked very well for us in the past.

Comment: CNAMES will still send the browser header for domain.com, and www.domain.com, he wants these perm redirected to main.domain.com, which will affect search ranking splits.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a functionality of web server. So let the webserver handle the request. So the most efficient way is using .htaccess redirect directives. 
Doing it using PHP is an inefficient way.